# laravel 5 doesn't find .env file

Tags: laravel-5

i have a WAMP server on my local which has .env file with variables set for DB and it work as expected. Then i have a remote shared host server which also has the .env file with variables for DB but i keep getting `Access denied for user 'forge'@'localhost'` and if i try to get value with `env('SOME_VARIABLE')`  which is set in the .env file I get an empty string. It seems that for some reason laravel can't find the .env file. is there a mod witch should be enabled or is there other reasons the variables isn't loaded?

Comment: Can you do this somewhere (in a route/controller): `Dotenv::load(base_path(), '.env');` if it can't load the file it should throw an exception.

Comment: So how do you solve this problem? I have the same one..

Answer (score 0):

Do you have permissions set correctly for the .env file on the remote server?  If the webserver doesn't have permission to read the file, it will not be able to load the config; depending on your settings, it may not stop here, and will continue to attempt to connect to the database without any config variables loaded.